# Can't make image folder static in expressjs

Tags: mongodb, image, express, multer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJkDj.png)

my api files are under nodejs folder as well as the uploads folder to where the images are being kept. But in order to send any request I need to go to nodejs.ibnhaysam.com/api/v1/[endpoint]. So when I want to get the image from the uploads folder I am suppose to type nodejs.ibnhaysam.com/imagename.ext which response me "The resource requested could not be found on this server!".

This is the multer code I am using to upload images to my server. Please let me know how may I get the images.

```
const path = require('path')
const multer = require('multer')

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, 'uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        let ext = path.extname(file.originalname)
        let fileName = Date.now() + '-' + ext
        cb(null, fileName)
    }
  })
  
  const upload = multer({ 
    storage: storage 
  })

  module.exports = upload
```

I have tried diferrent url but not a single url worked at all

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const uploadPath = '/nodejs.ibnhaysam.com/uploads';
    if (!fs.existsSync(uploadPath)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(uploadPath, { recursive: true });
    }
    callback(null, uploadPath);
```

You can define path upload folder like this to up image into nodejs.ibnhaysam.com folder. Hope it's helpfull.

Comment: Certainly I don't have permission to do so.